Least upper bound for $(0,2)\cap \mathbb{Q}$
I'm trying to understand the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$.
Is this reasoning correct (I know it might be a bit handwavy)? The set $\{r \in \mathbb{Q} : r^2 < 2\}$ has no least upper bound because no matter how close I get to $\sqrt{2}$ from above I can always find a rational number that is closer and I can't choose $\sqrt{2}$ itself because it's not rational.
If the above is correct, how about a least upper bound for the set $(0, 2) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Is 2 a least upperbound here? How I see it at the moment is that the difference here is that 2 $\in \mathbb{Q}$, so it should be fine. But I'm not sure.
Any help would be appreciated.

Yes to both questions.

As a subset of the real numbers, $A={r\in\mathbb Q: r^2<2}$ does have a supremum, namely exactly $\sqrt 2$. However, as you correctly stated, the rationals are dense in the reals and thus we can find fractions that are arbitrarily close to $\sqrt 2$. Therefore, as a subset of $\mathbb Q$, $A$ has no least upper bound.

Thank you both!

You are correct about both of the questions you pose. The proof you provide for the first is a bit hand-wavy, as you said, but you stated the ideas behind the more rigorous proof.

You can determine this formally by using the following argument.
Suppose $x \in \mathbb Q$ is the greatest upper bound of $(0, 2) \cap \mathbb Q$.
We know that $2$ is an upper bound of $(0, 2)$.
Hence $x \le 2$.
Suppose $x < 2$.
Then $x < \dfrac {x + 2} 2 < 2$ and so $x$ cannot be the greatest upper bound of $(0, 2) \cap \mathbb Q$ after all.
But we know that either $x < 2$ or $x = 2$.
But since $x \not < 2$ it must follow that $x = 2$.
